How to disable root menu root in oracle form 12c?
I need some help I am using Oracle Forms 12c to create menu, I know Set_menu_item_property('NameOfMenuRoot.NameOfMenuItem', visible, property_false); only apply to sub-menu item.
How to disable the entire menu root instead of item.

see docs: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/forms/11g/formsmenuscreate/formsmenuscreate.htm, and make clear what the problem is.

Are you trying to hide a top level menu item OR the entire menu bar?  To hide the top menu item, do what you already mentioned:  SET_MENU_ITEM_PROPERTY ('MENU1.TOP1', VISIBLE, PROPERTY_FALSE);  If you are trying to hide the entire menu bar after the app has started, there really is no practical way to do this.
